# rowcount in Forloop does not update when row is deleted

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to run this code in QTP which is for deleting records from a grid. This code

```
dgRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount
For i = 1 To dgRows 

SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").SelectCell i-1,0 
'row of data grid begins with 0, hence i -1
SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfButton("DELETE").Click
Swfwindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfWindow("RegionMaster").SwfButton("Insert").Click
    deleteCode = closePrompt()

If deleteCode = 15 Then 'closePrompt returns 15 when record is successfully deleted
    i = i - 1           'As record is deleted, grid has lost one record and for loop will exit early by one record or throw error.
 dgoRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount
End If
Next
```

This piece of code runs from 1 to number of rows in a grid (dgRows).

If there are 3 rows, it will run thrice and delete records if possible. If 1 record is deleted,
the grid loses a record. Hence I am trying to adjust the value of i and dgRows by the code

> i = i - 1    'As record is deleted, grid has lost one record and
> for loop will exit early by one record or throw error.
> dgoRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount
>
> 'Updating new value of dgRows so that QTP does not click on a row for value of i that does not
> exist.

I try to illustrate the issues I am facing with this piece of code

> dgRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region
> Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount

After row is deleted, it does not dynamically get the no of rows in the grid when the for loop iterates. Hence i value becomes equal to 3 rows but actually in the grid there is one row as 2 records have been deleted, thus QTP tries to click on a cell with i value 3 but doesn't find it and throws an error.

Can anyone tell me why doesn't ("dgMaster").RowCount update itself or how to update it when the for loop runs next?

Comment: When deleting rows, its common to actually iterate from the last element to the first with the step -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBScript a for loop only evaluates the limit once.

Proof:

```
limit = 4
For i = 1 to limit
    limit = limit - 1
    document.write(i & " - " & limit & "<br>")
Next
```

Output:

> 1 - 3
>   2 - 2
>   3 - 1
>   4 - 0

You should use a `While` loop instead

```
dgRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount
i = 1 ' I would use 0 but I'm keeping the code as close to original as possible
While i <= dgRows
    i = i + 1
    SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").SelectCell i-1,0 
    'row of data grid begins with 0, hence i -1
    SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfButton("DELETE").Click
    Swfwindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfWindow("RegionMaster").SwfButton("Insert").Click
    deleteCode = closePrompt()

    If deleteCode = 15 Then 'closePrompt returns 15 when record is successfully deleted
        i = i - 1           'As record is deleted, grid has lost one record and for loop will exit early by one record or throw error.
        dgoRows = SwfWindow("PWC - [PWC]").SwfWindow("Region Master").SwfTable("dgMaster").RowCount
    End If
WEnd
```

Comment: @user2181576 my pleasure, I actually didn't know this and found out thanks to your question so thank you!